# Ruby language cheatsheet/poster/reference/overview?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am a visual kind of guy and would like to know if there is somewhere a nice big overview of Ruby. You know, like a **reference poster**, *with object hierarchy*, most common methods, etc, all in color, layed out nice and clearly...

To a beginner like me would this would be awesome...

Is there something like that out there that you use or have stumbled upon?

Comment: https://ohmycheatsheet.com/ruby/ is good

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Check these out :**

- https://github.com/savini/cheatsheets/raw/master/ruby/RubyCheat.pdf
- http://wtr.rubyforge.org/s101/doc/Ruby-cheat-sheet.doc
- http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/essential-ruby#refcard-download-social-buttons-display

And a... "comparative" approach, with cheat sheets combined for major scripting languages :

- http://hyperpolyglot.org/scripting

Comment: downvote since downloads either is only for Ruby 1.x, or requires registration